insertar video de Youtube en html
Quiero insertar un video desde yutube en un documento html escrito desde block de notas pero no encuentra la direccion que estoy escribiendo mal lo estoy haciendo en block de notas con html y quiero insertar un videos de youtube
El código es este :


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<title>Mi sitio web</title>

<body>

<h1>Bienvenido</h1>

<br>

<br>

<video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PORH8P2ylPA" width="320" height="240" controls>

</video>

</body>

</html>




El elemento video espera que la URL de la propiedad SRC corresponda a un archivo de video. Sin embargo, un enlace a Youtube no corresponde a ningún video, sino a una página HTML.
Para insertar un vídeo de Youtube en tu propia página debes hacer clic en el botón Compartir del vídeo y elegir la opción Incorporar. Obtendrás un código HTML que consiste en un iframe. Justamente los iframe te permiten incrustar otro HTML o página web en tú propio sitio.
El código se ve algo así:


<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?si=2jFF1IyZvOIteUYp" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>



